# Eclipse RCP cannot find EclipseStarter

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application to develop; the code was written a couple of years ago, and I have to finish it. I imported the plugins in Eclipse, I solve all the dependencies, but when I try to launch it I get this error:

```
!SESSION Tue Mar 29 10:13:24 CEST 2011 
-----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2011-03-29 10:13:24.326
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 

org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

I try to reinstall the Eclipse zip (deleting all and reunzipping it), but it still not work. I try to start the application with the `-clean` option to rebuild the cache, but it still not work. But if I create some dummy hello-plugin with hello-feature and hello-product, all works fine. Anyone have some hints to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Heh.  I have an RCP application to develop, the code was written a couple of years ago, and I have to fix it.  Dependencies will _not_ resolve for me; must have downloaded 50 jar files today, and the last one is "not found" by eclipse although my eyes tell me the class file is in there... i'll be watching this question carefully :P

Comment: I cannot post the code, because is a 100 Mb project divided in four plug-in and one feature. I don't know if this problem derive from a bad Eclipse configuration or it's a bug of the developer, i just answer for people who have had the same problem and have solve it.

Comment: Ok the problem is solved, i just change the option `The product configuration us based on` from _features_ to _plug-ins_ and add all the dependencies with the button `Add Required Plug-ins`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok the problem is solved, i just change the option `The product configuration is based on` from *features* to *plug-ins* and add all the dependencies with the button `Add Required Plug-ins`. I don't know if this is the correct way, it just work.

Comment: `Add Required Plug-ins` is gray in my case.

Comment: @Val: add at least one plugin, then you can add its required ones: nothing requires nothing. If you have no clue, check your dependencies in the MANIFEST.

Comment: This is pretty far from step-by-step directions, maybe you can elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.

My OS is windows 7. I opened Eclipse (really RAD in my case) as an administrator. Opened with out any issues.