# Eclipse RCP cannot find extension definition "run"

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have an RCP application to develop; the code was written a couple of years ago, and I have to finish it. I imported the plugins in Eclipse, I solve all the dependencies, but when I try to launch it I get this error:

```
!SESSION 2011-04-06 09:12:58.203 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_24
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product myapp.core.product
Command-line arguments:  -product myapp.core.product -data C:\Users\Me\Documents\Workspace/../runtime-myapp.product -dev 

file:C:/Users/Me/Documents/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Myapp.product/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2011-04-06 09:12:59.662
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Executable extension definition for "run" not found.
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.throwException(ConfigurationElement.java:62)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:222)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:191)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1384)
```

If I export with wizard all go fine, but when I try to launch the exported application I get the same error.
Before this error I had a problem with dependencies, [but I solve it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535868/eclipse-rcp-cannot-find-eclipsestarter).

Anyone have some ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have placed the text *run* inside of an extension point attribute where a class name is expected.

I'd recommend that you open the type ConfigurationElement and set a breakpoint on line 222 and run your rcp app in the debugger.  You will be able to see more information that way.

Answer (score 1):

You are extending the `org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications` extension point but your extension is missing the `run` child of the application element. It should contain the class name of your implementation of `org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication`.

Answer (score -1):

no. "run" comming from EclipseAppHandle.run() : where is 
application = getConfiguration().createExecutableExtension("run");